# How to include virtual keyboard(numeric pad) in website?

Tags: php, jquery, html, templates

There is a form filling in my website, and i included virtual keyboard there, when user click in textarea, then virtual keyboard will appear, and in some forms user needs to fill numbers, so i want to include numeric pad in forms where should fill the numbers. I found one, but i cant include it.

I included scripts and css in my tpl file, first 3 of numpad, the rest of keyboard:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.keypad.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="jquery.keypad.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="keyboard.user.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="keyboard.css">




<main class="main" style="padding:0; overflow-x:initial">
    <div class="container">
        {include file="engine/modules/products/eogpo.php"}
    </div>
</main>
<div id="isTerminal"></div>
$(function () {
  $('#defaultKeypad').keypad();
});
<div id="modalError" class="modal info__modal" data-modal>
    <button data-izimodal-close="" class="modal__close">
        <svg class="icon icon-close"><use xlink:href="/images/sprite.svg#icon-close"></use></svg>
    </button>
    <div class="modalStyle">
        <h3 class="info__title" id="errorTitle"><?php echo _("Ошибка"); ?></h3>
        <div id="textError"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="modalInfo" class="modal info__modal" data-modal>
    <button data-izimodal-close="" class="modal__close">
        <svg class="icon icon-close"><use xlink:href="/images/sprite.svg#icon-close"></use></svg>
    </button>
    <div class="modalStyle">
        <div id="textInfo"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="overLoader" style="display: none"><img src="/templates/assets/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>
```

In tutorial written that I should write:

```
$(function () {
  $('#defaultKeypad').keypad();
});
```

to call the plugin with default options, so i wrote it in tpl file

so finally i include the numpad id in:

```
<fieldset class="field-set col col--4-12" style="false">
                    <label for="orderIIN" class="field-set__label checkList">
                        <?php echo _("IIN");?>
                    </label>
                    <input class=" field iin-masked datas" id="IIN0 defaultKeypad" type="text" name="IIN[]"  maxlength="12" />
                    <span class="small col" id="textKBM0"></span>
                    <span class="small col" id="loadingIIN0"></span>
                    <input class="datas" id="KBM0" type="hidden" name="KBM[]" value="" />
                    <input class="datas" id="clientID0" type="hidden" name="clientID[]" value="" />
                    <input class="datas" id="clientISN0" type="hidden" name="clientISN[]" value="" />
                    <input class="datas" id="clientNation0" type="hidden" name="clientNation[]" value="Kazakhstan" />

                </fieldset>
```

Keyboard js works fine, but numpad js still doesn't turn on, where am i doing wrong?

Comment: it needs jQuery library 1.7 or later. check if you've older version of jQuery

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: could you please change `id="IIN0 defaultKeypad"` to `id="defaultKeypad"`

Comment: @RecepKaradas tried both options, but no change

Comment: @atoms no errors, just doesn't show any numpads

Comment: if you inspect the div. Has it altered the contents of it?

Comment: @atoms honestly, i dont understand the question

Comment: you have no error messages in the console and nothing on screen has changed. I would check to see if the keypad has been rendered but isnt visible

Comment: I think you have to add http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.plugin.js too (before jquery.keypad.js).

Comment: @atoms i checked, it doesn't load at all. Apparently I connect it wrong

Comment: Would you accept a JS version?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing `jquery-ui` assets

**STEP 1 - INCLUDE JQUERY**

Append the below script tag on top of your page and delete the previous `jquery script tags`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

open the page with chrome, [open the developer tools by pressing `f12`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) and make sure that you have the following files under `Sources` tab:

1. jquery.min.js
2. jquery-ui.min.js
3. jquery-ui.css

[image]

**STEP 2 - INCLUDE JQUERY KEYPAD CSS AND JS**

[Download `jquery.keypad.css`, `jquery.plugin.js` and `jquery.keypad.js` from here](http://keith-wood.name/zip/jquery.keypad.package-2.1.1.zip)

Unzip the file `jquery.keypad.package-2.2.1` and move them to the respective `js` and `css` folder of your project.

Add on top of your page, after the `jquery` script tag the following script.

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.keypad.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.keypad.js"></script>
```

As explained above, refresh and verify that the assets are included in your application

[image]

**STEP 3 - INCLUDE JQUERY KEYPAD CSS AND JS**

[Open your chrome developer console](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=chrome+developer+tools+how+to+open+the+console&atb=v153-6_l&ia=web) to run the following commands:

```
$(selector).keypad();
```

where selector is replaced from the `#id` or `.class` of your div. In your case should be:

```
$('#defaultKeypad').keypad();
```

I selected a div from the page as in the below picture

[[image]

then I run `.keypad()` and the `.keypad()` show in the page

[image]

you can find all the instruction and you can also test the functionality [on this page](http://keith-wood.name/keypad.html)

Comment: still doesn't work, probably this JS conflicts with another file

Comment: @ArsenOspanov then you comment each js file one at the time until it starts working, so you can understand which js file is breaking it, but I don't believe that you have a conflict. The problem is that you are including `jquery-min.js` while you should follow the instructions which allows you to have jquery + jquery-ui assets. If you don't want to follow the tutorial, at least make sure that you correctly install jquery-ui as on https://jqueryui.com/.

Comment: @ArsenOspanov Once you are sure that the assets are included, remove all your stylesheets too (expect those required in this functonalities) and try to run `$('#defaultKeypad').keypad();` in your console

Comment: The filling form conflicts with `jquery.js`, I downloaded it on the jqueryui.com, when i included it, my filling form is gone

Comment: @ArsenOspanov I tested and it does work with `<fieldset><input id="defaultKeypad"></fieldset>`. So maybe some of the the other classes are causing the problem.

Comment: i found it, my form filling has another js files, and i removed them for the test, and it all worked, now i need to deal with JS files, and resolve conflict) thank you very much, you've helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the JQ version but I just made this one up.

Each textbox will have it own id and onclick event:

```
showKeyPad(x, y, this.id):
x = margin-left
y = margin-top
```

You can set x and y to null to ignore.

Even if it is not what you would like, I enjoyed making it and anyone is welcome to improve it in anyway. Totally free without ads :)
Copy Paste the following to give it a trial.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
             #keypad{
                  position: absolute;
                  background-color: lightblue;
                  margin-left: 20vw;
                  margin-top: 20vh;
                  width: 14vw;
                  height: 30vh;
                  border-color: grey;
                  border-width: 1px;
                  border-style: solid;
                  border-radius: 2%;
             }

            .keypads{
                 display: inline;
                 width: 28%;
                 height: 19%;
                 margin-top: 5%;
                 margin-left: 3%;
                 border-color: grey;
                 border-width: 1px;
                 border-style: solid;
                 border-radius: 2%;
           }


          </style>
          <script type="text/javascript">
               var focused;
               function showKeypad(x, y, tBox){
                     var keypad = document.getElementById("keypad");
                     if(x != null && y != null){
                         keypad.style.marginLeft = x + "vw";             //Setting x and y are optional but it can be 
                         keypad.style.marginTop = y + "vh";             //      set to render near textboxes   // Set x & y to 0 to ignore
                     }
                     keypad.style.display = "block";
                     window.focused = document.getElementById(tBox);
                 }

                 function hideKeyPad(){
                      var keypad = document.getElementById("keypad");
                      keypad.style.display = "none";
                 }

                function SendInputs(input){
                      if(focused){
                            if(input != "CE"){
                                 var oldText = focused.value;
                                 oldText += input;
                                 focused.value = oldText;
                             }else
                             {
                                  focused.value = "";
                             }
                       }else hideKeyPad();
                }
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>


      <div id="keypad" style="display: none;">
            <input type="button" class="keypads" value="1" onclick="SendInputs('1')">
            <input type="button" class="keypads" value="2" onclick="SendInputs('2')">
            <input type="button" class="keypads" value="3" onclick="SendInputs('3')"><br>
            <input type="button" class="keypads" value="4" onclick="SendInputs('4')">
            <input type="button" class="keypads" value="5" onclick="SendInputs('5')">
           <input type="button" class="keypads" value="6" onclick="SendInputs('6')"><br>
           <input type="button" class="keypads" value="7" onclick="SendInputs('7')">
           <input type="button" class="keypads" value="8" onclick="SendInputs('8')">
          <input type="button" class="keypads" value="9" onclick="SendInputs('9')"><br>
           <input type="button" class="keypads" value="CE" style="color:red;" onclick="SendInputs('CE')">
          <input type="button" class="keypads" value="0" onclick="SendInputs('0')">
          <input type="button" class="keypads" value="X" style="color:red;" onclick="hideKeyPad()">

       </div>

       <div>
             <input id="Phone" type="text" onclick="showKeypad(5, 10, this.id)">
              <input type="text" >
              <input type="text" >
              <input type="text" >
              <input id="ID" type="text" onclick="showKeypad(50, 10, this.id)">
              <input type="text" >
              <input type="text" >
              <input id="DOB" type="text" onclick="showKeypad(80, 10, this.id)">
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```